# reading specific number of values in TCP connection

Tags: matlab, tcp

Im using matlab TCP connection to read the values of a stream data come from external device, the problem is when I used `data=fscanf(t , "%d")` where `t` is a TCP object, it reads a different number of values at each time, but I don't want it to do this, I want to read a 46 values at the same time. 
Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Use size parameter of `fscanf` to read at most 46 values and trigger reading with the `BytesAvailableFcn` to start it not before 46 values are available.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks, its worked, Could you repost it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To receive fixed size chunks of 46 values, use the size parameter of `fscanf` to receive not more than 46 values. Now this receiving has to be triggered only if enough data is available. Best practice is to use the `BytesAvailableFcn`. If configured with the correct size, it is triggered every time 46 values are available.

Comment: if we have 46 integer values, what `BytesAvailableFcn` should be? does the integer in tcp connection equals to 4 bytes?